# OpenGL ES surface size, hidden Android software navigation bar, and Google Play Games

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es, google-play-games, navigationbar

I recently realised that I should hide the navigation bar and use Immersive mode in my Android app. I've ran into a tricky issue where the OpenGL surface is created during the automatic login process of Google Play Games. The navigation bar is still visible during this, and the `GLSurfaceView` sizes itself to account for this, leaving a black bar at the bottom of the screen after the nav bar disappears. I'm using the [BaseGameUtils](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils) package provided by Google, which means that my base `Activity` extends the `BaseGameActivity` class from said package, therefore running the superclass constructor before running any of my code. Thus, I find myself unable to ensure that the OpenGL ES surface is created before the login process begins. This means that even when I set the `Window` flags `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` and `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY` in the `onCreate()` of my own `Activity` class, the navigation bar is still brought up during the login process. I've tried changing the flags in `BaseGameActivity` as well, to no avail; I'm fairly certain the problem lies in the various popups that are brought up that seem to come directly from `GoogleApiClient` where I cannot modify them.

A full recreation of the `GLSurfaceView`, such as pressing the home button and then returning to the app, sets the `Surface` size correctly. However, doing this requires a full reload of all textures, which I cannot have happen after the app has already started. I'm looking for solutions that would either allow me to:

- Create the `GLSurfaceView` before the Google Play Games login process begins. I'm not certain this is possible at all, but if anyone has experience to the contrary it should solve the issue entirely.
- Trigger a "reset" of the `GLSurfaceView`, so it resizes itself without having to reload textures, or
- Stop the `BaseGameUtils` package from bringing up the nav bar at all.

Other solutions are, of course, welcome as well.

Comment: If you use a SurfaceView rather than a GLSurfaceView, you will have full control over the lifespan of the EGLSurface. See Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) for multiple examples.

Answer (score 0):

It may not solve all your problems, but you can definitely get rid of BaseGameActivity and BaseGameUtils.  There is an informative video about this change:  [Game On! - The death of BaseGameActivity](http://youtu.be/1oSoaFLuTwM).  The recommended approach is to have your activity (or ActivityFragment) implement the 2 interfaces needed for connecting: [GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks), [GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener).

The [TypeANumber](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/TypeANumber/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/tanc/MainActivity.java) sample is a good model to follow.

This should allow you to integrate all your initialization code and the sign-in handling without issue.

As far as far are creating the GLSurfaceView before the login process, this should be fine.  Once your view is initialized and your game is ready to go, you can call GoogleAPIClient.connect() to start the process.

If you are familiar with C++ at all, you can browse the code of the C++ basic game samples which use OpenGL and Play Game Services: https://github.com/playgameservices/cpp-android-basic-samples.